How to forward one IP request to another port
Due to some issues in my country (Iran), I have some connectivity issue with an API like this:
https://api.another.website.com

I know the above URL, but it's included in an encoded PHP file with IonCube Loader, so I cannot change the URL.
I'm going to do this:
If I run curl https://api.another.website.com, it should change it to curl https://api.another.website.com:9999

What I've done is:

Edit /etc/hosts and add this entry: 1.1.1.1 api.another.website.com (in this case, 1.1.1.1 is my server IP)
I run this SSH command to open a local forwarding: ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9999:api.another.website.com:443 root@remote_server

The other thing I don't know is what to do in iptables.
I googled and figured out something like this I should add in iptables:
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -t nat -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 1.1.1.1:9999

But the issue I have with above code (and I think what I understood) is that it redirects all 443 requests to 9999, but I don't know how to forward port 443 for one IP or one domain only.
Would you please help me how to do it?

Use -d to match the destination IP address. In this case, 1.1.1.1 is the original destination address (as resolved through /etc/hosts), so use -d 1.1.1.1.
If you don't want to affect regular traffic to your VPS:443, use a fake address instead (both in your /etc/hosts and in the -d option).

Thanks, but where to add domain api.another.website.com in the iptables command? Also suppose I am going to add multiple domains, how can I do that? I mean suppose I have api2, api3, etc. in the future.

You don't - iptables doesn't deal with DNS, it works exclusively at IP level after the domain has already been resolved to something. The plan relies on your /etc/hosts assigning the addresses.
